# How to escape os.system() calls?

Tags: python, shell, escaping

When using os.system() it's often necessary to escape filenames and other arguments passed as parameters to commands.  How can I do this?  Preferably something that would work on multiple operating systems/shells but in particular for bash.

I'm currently doing the following, but am sure there must be a library function for this, or at least a more elegant/robust/efficient option:

```py
def sh_escape(s):
   return s.replace("(","\\(").replace(")","\\)").replace(" ","\\ ")

os.system("cat %s | grep something | sort > %s" 
          % (sh_escape(in_filename), 
             sh_escape(out_filename)))
```

*Edit:* I've accepted the simple answer of using quotes, don't know why I didn't think of that; I guess because I came from Windows where ' and " behave a little differently.

Regarding security, I understand the concern, but, in this case, I'm interested in a quick and easy solution which os.system() provides, and the source of the strings is either not user-generated or at least entered by a trusted user (me).

Comment: Beware of the security issue!
For instance if out_filename is foo.txt; rm -rf / The malicious user can add more command directly interpreted by the shell.

Comment: This is also useful without os.system, in situations where subprocess isn't even an option; e.g. generating shell scripts.

Comment: An ideal `sh_escape` function would escape out the `;` and spaces and remove the security problem by simply creating a file called something like `foo.txt\;\ rm\ -rf\ /`.

Comment: In almost all cases, you should use subprocess, not os.system. Calling os.system is just asking for an injection attack.

Comment: Remember that it's not enough to merely escape the argument for the shell to make this secure, you also have to watch out for arguments beginning with dash or unexpected paths when filenames were intended.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
def shellquote(s):
    return "'" + s.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"
```

The shell will always accept a quoted filename and remove the surrounding quotes before passing it to the program in question. Notably, this avoids problems with filenames that contain spaces or any other kind of nasty shell metacharacter.

**Update**: If you are using Python 3.3 or later, use [shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: While this is hardly the responsibility of the shellquote function, it might be interesting to note that this will still fail if an unquoted backslash appears just before the return value of this function.
Morale: make sure you use this in code that you can trust as safe - (such as part of hardcoded commands) - don't append it to other unquoted user input.

Comment: Note that unless you absolutely need shell features, you should probably be using Jamie's suggestion instead.

Comment: Something similar to this is now officially available as [shlex.quote](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote).

Comment: @lhunath completely wrong on both counts. This is the perfect and proper way to escape a word for POSIX shell (note the wording “a word”, the command structure is up to the user, but trivial to do). Passing as list does not help e.g. after an `ssh` command, since you need to escape multiple levels then…

Comment: The function provided in this answer does a better job of shell quoting than `shlex` or `pipes`. Those python modules erroneously assume that special characters are the only thing which need to be quoted, which means that shell keywords (like `time`, `case` or `while`) will be parsed when that behaviour is not expected. For that reason I would recommend using the single-quoting routine in this answer, because it doesn't try to be "clever" so doesn't have those silly edge cases.

Comment: Something this solution doesn't address is if there's '/' embedded in a filename. The shell will barf on that because it doesn't allow that character in path name components.

Comment: Also present in python 2.7 - https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/shlex.html

Comment: I believe `"'" + s.replace("'", "'\"'\"'") + "'"` works even better because it doesn't require backslash to be interpreted as special before double quote in shell.

Comment: `print(shlex.quote("filename'"))` fails :( it prints `'filename'"'"''` Where to report bug?

Comment: should also throw an error if there's any null bytes

Answer (score 188):

[`shlex.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) does what you want since python 3.

(Use [`pipes.quote`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) to support both python 2 and python 3,
though note that `pipes` has been deprecated since 3.10
and slated for removal in 3.13)

Comment: There's also `commands.mkarg`. It also adds a leading space (outside the quotes) which may or may not be desirable.It's interesting how their implementations are quite different from each other, and also much more complicated than Greg Hewgill's answer.

Comment: For some reason, `pipes.quote` is not mentioned by the [standard library documentation for the pipes module](http://docs.python.org/library/pipes.html)

Comment: Both are undocumented; `command.mkarg` is deprecated and removed in 3.x, while pipes.quote remained.

Comment: Correction: officially documented as [`shlex.quote()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/py3k/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) in 3.3 , `pipes.quote()` retained for compatibility.  [http://bugs.python.org/issue9723]

Comment: pipes does NOT work on Windows - adds single quotes insted of double quotes.

Comment: shlex appears quite limited and doesn't do what Op wants. For example, the string 'hello"there' should have the double-quote escaped, since that's a special character in sh. But shlex.quote() does not escape it, resulting in a malformed shell call.

Comment: @Cerin `shlex.quote('hello"there')` returns the string `'\'hello"there\''`, which when printed is displayed as `'hello"there'`. This is correct escaping for POSIX shells like Bash and Zsh, which treat everything between single quotes literally. As proof, `touch 'hello"there'` will create a file named `hello"there`

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. Recent Python docs say:

"Warning = The shlex module is only designed for Unix shells."

Answer (score 65):

Perhaps you have a specific reason for using `os.system()`. But if not you should probably be using the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html). You can specify the pipes directly and avoid using the shell.

The following is from [PEP324](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/):

> ```
> Replacing shell pipe line
> -------------------------
>
> output=`dmesg | grep hda`
> ==>
> p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
> p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
> output = p2.communicate()[0]
> ```

Comment: `subprocess` (especially with `check_call` etc) is often dramatically superior, but there are a few cases where shell escaping is still useful. The main one I'm running into is when I'm having to invoke ssh remote commands.

Comment: @CraigRinger, yup, ssh remoting is what brought me here.  :P  I wish ssh had something to help here.

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard It does seem odd that it doesn't have an --execvp-remote option (or work that way by default). Doing everything through the shell seems clumsy and risky. OTOH, ssh is full of weird quirks, often things done in a narrow view of "security" that causes people to come up with way-more-insecure workarounds.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe `subprocess.list2cmdline` is a better shot?

Comment: That looks pretty good. Interesting it isn't documented... (in http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html at least)

Comment: It does not properly escape \: `subprocess.list2cmdline(["'",'',"\\",'"'])` gives `' "" \ \"`

Comment: It does not escape shell expansion symbols

Comment: Is subprocess.list2cmdline() intended only for Windows?

Comment: @JS Yes, `list2cmdline` conforms to Windows cmd.exe syntax ([see the function docstring in the Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/subprocess.py#L516)). `shlex.quote` conforms to Unix bourne shell syntax, however it isn't usually necessary since Unix has good support for directly passing arguments. Windows pretty much requires that you pass a single string with all your arguments (thus the need for proper escaping).

Answer (score 6):

Note that pipes.quote is actually broken in Python 2.5 and Python 3.1 and not safe to use--It doesn't handle zero-length arguments.

```
>>> from pipes import quote
>>> args = ['arg1', '', 'arg3']
>>> print 'mycommand %s' % (' '.join(quote(arg) for arg in args))
mycommand arg1  arg3
```

See [Python issue 7476](http://bugs.python.org/issue7476); it has been fixed in Python 2.6 and 3.2 and newer.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Version 2.6 seems to produce the correct output: mycommand arg1 '' arg3  (Those are two single-quotes together, though the font on Stack Overflow makes that hard to tell!)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that os.system just invokes whatever command shell is configured for the user, so I don't think you can do it in a platform independent way.  My command shell could be anything from bash, emacs, ruby, or even quake3.  Some of these programs aren't expecting the kind of arguments you are passing to them and even if they did there is no guarantee they do their escaping the same way.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to expect a mostly or fully POSIX-compliant shell (at least everywhere but with Windows, and you know what "shell" you have then, anyway).  os.system doesn't use $SHELL, at least not here.

Answer (score 3):

**Notice**: This is an answer for Python 2.7.x.

According to the [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/pipes.py#l262), `pipes.quote()` is a way to "*Reliably quote a string as a single argument for **/bin/sh***". (Although it is [deprecated since version 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pipes.html#pipes.quote) and finally exposed publicly in Python 3.3 as the `shlex.quote()` function.)

On [the other hand](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/subprocess.py#l577), `subprocess.list2cmdline()` is a way to "*Translate a sequence of arguments into a command line string, using the same rules as the **MS C runtime***".

Here we are, the platform independent way of quoting strings for command lines.

```
import sys
mswindows = (sys.platform == "win32")

if mswindows:
    from subprocess import list2cmdline
    quote_args = list2cmdline
else:
    # POSIX
    from pipes import quote

    def quote_args(seq):
        return ' '.join(quote(arg) for arg in seq)
```

Usage:

```
# Quote a single argument
print quote_args(['my argument'])

# Quote multiple arguments
my_args = ['This', 'is', 'my arguments']
print quote_args(my_args)
```

Answer (score 2):

The function I use is:

```py
def quote_argument(argument):
    return '"%s"' % (
        argument
        .replace('\\', '\\\\')
        .replace('"', '\\"')
        .replace('$', '\\$')
        .replace('`', '\\`')
    )
```

that is: I always enclose the argument in double quotes, and then backslash-quote the only characters special inside double quotes.

Comment: Note that you should use '\\"', '\\$' and '\\`', otherwise the escaping doesn't happen.

Comment: Additionally, [there are issues with using double quotes in some (weird) locales](http://bugs.python.org/issue22187); the suggested fix uses `pipes.quote` which @JohnWiseman pointed out is also broken.  Greg Hewgill’s answer is thus the one to use. (It’s also the one the shells use internally for the regular cases.)

Comment: Thanks. This works every well for my case. It is python3.5 and the shlex does not have escape method either while the quote method dose not help when the text contains $$$

Answer (score 0):

On UNIX shells like Bash, you can use `shlex.quote` in Python 3 to escape special characters that the shell might interpret, like whitespace and the `*` character:

```py
import os
import shlex

os.system("rm " + shlex.quote(filename))
```

However, this is not enough for security purposes! You still need to be careful that the command argument is not interpreted in unintended ways. For example, what if the filename is actually a path like `../../etc/passwd`? Running `os.system("rm " + shlex.quote(filename))` might delete `/etc/passwd` when you only expected it to delete filenames found in the current directory! The issue here isn't with the shell interpreting special characters, it's that the filename argument isn't interpreted by the `rm` as a simple filename, it's actually interpreted as a path.

Or what if the valid filename starts with a dash, for example, `-f`? It's not enough to merely pass the escaped filename, you  need to disable options using `--` or you need to pass a path that doesn't begin with a dash like `./-f`. The issue here isn't with the shell interpreting special characters, it's that the `rm` command interprets the argument as a filename *or* a path *or* an option if it begins with a dash.

Here is a safer implementation:

```py
if os.sep in filename:
     raise Exception("Did not expect to find file path separator in file name")

os.system("rm -- " + shlex.quote(filename))
```

Comment: My answer was also deleted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSPJD.png

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Your answer should not have been deleted.

Comment: They are deleting everything they don't like, regardless of the SE policy: [answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETzjo.png), [comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxXf7.png) (posted on https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5077/18147, later undeleted by the mod), [chat messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEyyD.jpg), etc. Happy to send more via email so that we don't clutter this comment section, you can ping me on franck.dernoncourt@gmail.com (we can't use chat because I'm chat banned by the same mods).

Answer (score 0):

I think these answers are a bad idea for escaping command-line arguments on Windows. Based on the results: people are trying to apply a black-list approach to filtering 'bad' characters, assuming (and hoping) they got them all. Windows is very complex and there could be all manner of characters found in the future that might allow an attacker to hijack command line arguments.

I've already seen some answers neglect to filter basic meta-characters in Windows (like the semi-colon.) The approach I take is far simpler:

1. Make a list of allowed ASCII characters.
2. Remove all chars that aren't in that list.
3. Escape slashes and double-quotes.
4. Surround entire command with double quotes so the command argument cannot be maliciously broken and commandeered with spaces.

A basic example:

```py
def win_arg_escape(arg, allow_vars=0):
    allowed_list = """'"/\\abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-. """
    if allow_vars:
        allowed_list += "~%$"

    # Filter out anything that isn't a
    # standard character.
    buf = ""
    for ch in arg:
        if ch in allowed_list:
            buf += ch

    # Escape all slashes.
    buf = buf.replace("\\", "\\\\")

    # Escape double quotes.
    buf = buf.replace('"', '""')

    # Surround entire arg with quotes.
    # This avoids spaces breaking a command.
    buf = '"%s"' % (buf)

    return buf
```

The function has an option to enable use of environmental variables and other shell variables. Enabling this poses more risk so its disabled by default.