# Python - Spaces in Filenames

Tags: python, linux, file-io, module

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape os.system() calls in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls-in-python)

Is there a Python method of making filenames safe (ie. putting \ infront of spaces and escaping ( , ), symbols) programatically in Python?

Comment: give a use case of what you actually want to do because Python can take care of files with spaces pretty well.

Comment: Areeed, @ghostdog74. Safe for or from what?

Answer (score 3):

Spaces are already "safe" for Python in `open()`. As for `os.system()` and similar functions, use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import pipes
>>> pipes.quote("\&*!")
"'\\&*!'"
```

Comment: +1 for the relatively unknown `pipes` module, even if it's uncertain whether the OP is working on a Unix/Linux system.