# Retrieving the command executed by subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

I am executing a command via Python's subprocess module. How can I view the full command that was executed?
For instance, if I submitted `['ls', '-l']`, I would like an easy way to see 'ls -l'.

Comment: Why not do `' '.join(my_list)`? You're calling subprocess so you already know the full command.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do the reverse of `shlex.split()`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692873/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967443/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
ls = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '/tmp'])
cmd = file("/proc/%d/cmdline" % (ls.pid)).read()
```

See [The /proc Filesystem](http://linux.startcom.org/docs/de/Introduction%20to%20Linux/x8608.html) for more info and ideas.

Note that some commands will ask you for privileges.

Of course you could (as Simeon has pointed out) apply `join` to the list you passed to `Popen`.