# Escape special characters in a Python string

Tags: python, string, escaping

Does Python have a function that I can use to escape special characters in a string?

For example, `I'm "stuck" :\` should become `I\'m \"stuck\" :\\`.

Comment: What do you consider to be a special character?

Comment: Completely depends on your context. Usually those characters are totally fine when you have them inside a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping regex string in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python)

Comment: The question originally did not say anything about regular expressions but this was only added in an edit three years later. Since we already have a good canonical for escaping regex strings, I have reverted the question to its original meaning since the majority of answers are also not in response to this special case.

Comment: @poke as you noted at the time, the question is not answerable as asked, because neither "escape" nor "special" is properly defined. For example, should a newline be left alone? Have a backslash inserted before it? Turned into a backslash followed by lowercase n? Turned into a backslash followed by lowercase x followed by zero followed by lowercase a? Something else?

Comment: Related: [`unicode-escape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9339658/5267751), [`shlex.quote`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817/5267751).

Answer (score 260, accepted):

Use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape(r'\ a.*$')
'\\\\\\ a\\.\\*\\$'
>>> print(re.escape(r'\ a.*$'))
\\\ a\.\*\$
>>> re.escape('www.stackoverflow.com')
'www\\.stackoverflow\\.com'
>>> print(re.escape('www.stackoverflow.com'))
www\.stackoverflow\.com
```

Repeating it here:

> re.escape(string)
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

As of Python 3.7 `re.escape()` was changed to escape only characters which are meaningful to regex operations.

Comment: You may use regex module instead of re. An example would be  `regex.escape(pattern,string,special_only=True`

Comment: Note that `re.escape` will turn e.g. a newline into a backslash followed by a newline; one might well instead want a backslash followed by a lowercase n.

Answer (score 23):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned using regular expressions via `re.sub()`:

```
import re
print re.sub(r'([\"])',    r'\\\1', 'it\'s "this"')  # it's \"this\"
print re.sub(r"([\'])",    r'\\\1', 'it\'s "this"')  # it\'s "this"
print re.sub(r'([\" \'])', r'\\\1', 'it\'s "this"')  # it\'s\ \"this\"
```

Important things to note:

- In the **search** pattern, include `\` as well as the character(s) you're looking for.
  You're going to be using `\` to escape your characters, so you need to escape
  *that* as well.
- Put parentheses around the **search** pattern, e.g. `([\"])`, so that the **substitution**
  pattern can use the found character when it adds `\` in front of it. (That's what
  `\1` does: uses the value of the first parenthesized group.)
- The `r` in front of `r'([\"])'` means it's a *raw string*. Raw strings use different
  rules for escaping backslashes. To write `([\"])` as a plain string, you'd need to
  double all the backslashes and write `'([\\"])'`. Raw strings are friendlier when
  you're writing regular expressions.
- In the **substitution** pattern, you need to escape `\` to distinguish it from a
  backslash that precedes a substitution group, e.g. `\1`, hence `r'\\\1'`. To write
  *that* as a plain string, you'd need `'\\\\\\1'` — and nobody wants that.

Answer (score 10):

Use repr()[1:-1]. In this case, the double quotes don't need to be escaped. The [-1:1] slice is to remove the single quote from the beginning and the end.

```
>>> x = raw_input()
I'm "stuck" :\
>>> print x
I'm "stuck" :\
>>> print repr(x)[1:-1]
I\'m "stuck" :\\
```

Or maybe you just want to escape a phrase to paste into your program? If so, do this:

```
>>> raw_input()
I'm "stuck" :\
'I\'m "stuck" :\\'
```

Comment: That doesn't work if the string is unicode, because you will have u and should run `repr(x)[2:-1]`

Comment: In python3.4, where all strings are unicode, this doesn't seem to work at all, unfortunately. Instead, `print(repr("I'm stuck")[1:-1])` prints  `I'm stuck`.

Comment: @dantiston this isn't because of the fact that the strings are all Unicode; it's because your example doesn't trigger `repr` to see a single quote as requiring escaping.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel with seven years of hindsight, I agree; this answer only works in certain circumstances, not the general case of escaping special characters.

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned above, the answer depends on your case. If you want to escape a string for a regular expression then you should use re.escape(). But if you want to escape a specific set of characters then use this lambda function:

```
>>> escape = lambda s, escapechar, specialchars: "".join(escapechar + c if c in specialchars or c == escapechar else c for c in s)
>>> s = raw_input()
I'm "stuck" :\
>>> print s
I'm "stuck" :\
>>> print escape(s, "\\", ['"'])
I'm \"stuck\" :\\
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to replace some characters you could use this:

```
import re

print re.sub(r'([\.\\\+\*\?\[\^\]\$\(\)\{\}\!\<\>\|\:\-])', r'\\\1', "example string.")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Note: This answer was written in response to the original question which was written in a way that it asked for a generic *“function which can [be used] to escape special characters”*, without specifying that these would be used for regular expressions, and without further specifying *what* special characters would have to be escaped.

In order to escape an arbitrary set of “special characters”, you can write a custom function that replaces each of these characters with an escaped variant. Something like this:

```
def escapeSpecialCharacters ( text, characters ):
    for character in characters:
        text = text.replace( character, '\\' + character )
    return text

>>> escapeSpecialCharacters( 'I\'m "stuck" :\\', '\'"' )
'I\\\'m \\"stuck\\" :\\'
>>> print( _ )
I\'m \"stuck\" :\
```

Comment: If backslash is one of the `characters` it had better be the first one!

Answer (score 0):

use json:

```
import json
print(r"""(I'm "stuck" :\)""")               # (I'm "stuck" :\)
print(json.dumps(r"""(I'm "stuck" :\)"""))   # (I'm "stuck" :\)
```

for json to string with escape character

```
json.dumps(json.dumps(d))
```