# Unescaping escaped characters in a string using Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a string in Python 3.2 like this:

```
'\n'
```

When I print() it to the console, it shows as a new line, obviously.  What I want is to be able to print it literally as a backslash followed by an n.  Further, I need to do this for all escaped characters, such as \t.  So I'm looking for a function unescape() that, for the general case, would work as follows:

```
>>> s = '\n\t'
>>> print(unescape(s)) 
'\\n\\t'
```

Is this possible in Python without constructing a dictionary of escaped characters to their literal replacements?

(In case anyone is interested, the reason I am doing this is because I need to pass the string to an external program on the command line.  This program understands all the standard escape sequences.)

Comment: When you say "one the command line" I assume you actually mean via stdout, in which case the program you are passing the data to should consume the `\n`,etc... without any problems.  That is, if you printed the data after it was passed into this second program, you would see the `\n` would still be there.  Unless you really do want to escape it.  But check first, if your just removing the extra `\` in the second program, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: I have a command line program called myutility. It expects to be called like this:
`myutility -i \n`
If I don't unescape the string then it won't ever see the \n being passed in to it - it will assume -i to be an empty argument.

Comment: Related question, [Escape special characters in a Python string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/escape-special-characters-in-a-python-string)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To prevent special treatment of `\` in a literal string you could use `r` prefix:

```
s = r'\n'
print(s)
# -> \n
```

If you have a string that contains a newline symbol (`ord(s) == 10`) and you would like to convert it to a form suitable as a Python literal:

```
s = '\n'
s = s.encode('unicode-escape').decode()
print(s)
# -> \n
```

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Based on your last remark, you likely want to get from Unicode to some encoded representation. This is one way:

```
>>> s = '\n\t'
>>> s.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\n\\t'
```

If you don't need them to be escaped then use your system encoding, e.g.:

```
>>> s.encode('utf8')
b'\n\t'
```

You could use that in a subprocess:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen([ 'myutility', '-i', s.encode('utf8') ], 
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
```

Comment: Although `repr()` is really attractive, this _might_ not be exactly what is intended, as this will actually output a string containing the single quotes, so you'll end up with something like `"'\\n\\r'"`.

Comment: My Python evaluates that as 
"'\\n\\t'"
I guess I can just strip the first and last characters...?

Comment: `repr('\n\t')` returns `"'\\n\\t'"`

Comment: Remark: `unicode-escape`, unlike `repr`, will also escape characters outside the ASCII range e.g. `⊕` becomes `\u2295`.