# Print escaped representation of a str

Tags: python, escaping

How do I print the escaped representation of a string, for example if I have:

```
s = "String:\tA"
```

I wish to output:

```
String:\tA
```

on the screen instead of

```
String:    A
```

The equivalent function in java is:

```
String xy = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(yourString);
System.out.println(xy);
```

from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/python-escape-special-characters) may be of interest to you, though the solution escapes a bit more than what you want..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want to encode the string with the `string_escape` codec:

```
print s.encode('string_escape')
```

or you can use the [`repr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr), which will turn a string into it's python literal representation *including the quotes*:

```
print repr(s)
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> s = "String:\tA"
>>> print s.encode('string_escape')
String:\tA
>>> print repr(s)
'String:\tA'
```

In Python 3, you'd be looking for the `unicode_escape` codec instead:

```
print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
```

which will print a bytes value. To turn that back into a unicode value, just decode from ASCII:

```
>>> s = "String:\tA"
>>> print(s.encode('unicode_escape'))
b'String:\\tA'
>>> print(s.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ASCII'))
String:\tA
```

Comment: I just want to say again that this is neat.  As one who works almost entirely in ASCII, I don't think of encoding very often -- (though I'm trying to be more mindful of that stuff). -- Unfortunately, now that you're the top answer, mine will likely stop getting upvotes ;-).

Comment: @mgilson I upvote Martjin's answer because I wasn't aware of the existence of 'string_escape' and mgilson's answer because I'm in a good humor :)

Answer (score 12):

you can use [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr):

```
print repr(s)
```

demo

```
>>> s = "String:\tA"
>>> print repr(s)
'String:\tA'
```

This will give the quotes -- but you can slice those off easily:

```
>>> print repr(s)[1:-1]
String:\tA
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Never seen that before.  neat.  +1 to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Give `print repr(string)` a shot

Answer (score 0):

As ever, its easy in python:

```
print(repr(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` uses `str`, which processes escapes. You want `repr`.

```
>>> a = "Hello\tbye\n"
>>> print str(a)
Hello   bye

>>> print repr(a)
'Hello\tbye\n'
```