# Getting .decode("hex") to display results as normal charcters and escaped hex when run from .py

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I type `"32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee".decode('hex')` into the shell the output looks like `2Q\x0b\xa9\xba\xbe\xbb\xbe\xfd\x00\x15G\xa8\x10\xe6qI\xca\xee`'
which is what I want.

However if I run this from a `.py` script nothing gets printed.
If I change the code to

`print "32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee".decode('hex')`

I get all kinds of symbols displayed like  ♬, for example

Comment: The problem is when I use print it displays symbols instead of escaped hex

Comment: For what do you want the escaped python representation of a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960885/print-escaped-representation-of-a-str

Comment: What are you doing with the data?

Comment: Inspecting it to see what the original ascii was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
print "32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee".decode('hex').encode('string-escape')
```

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to what the python shell does:

```
print repr("32510ba9babebbbefd001547a810e67149caee".decode('hex'))
```

Comment: @k29: this answer and naltipar's are subtly different - `repr` includes the surrounding quotes, `.encode('string-escape')` does not.

Comment: True; both answers essentially do what I require: display the string as escaped hex.