# Adding "\" to a String Python | How to insert a "\" before each paren in a string?

Tags: python

How would I add the `"\"` char to a string?

For instance, if I have `"testme"` and I do

```
"testme"+"\"
```

I would get an error.

What is a "pythonic" approach for adding a `"\"` before each paren in a string?

For instance to go from `"(hi)" to "\(hi\)"`

My current approach is to iterate through each char and try to append a `"\"` which I feel isn't that "pythonic"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/python-escape-special-characters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Backslashes are used for escaping various characters, so to include a literal backslash in your string you need to use `"\\"`, for example:

```
>>> print "testme" + "\\"
testme\
```

So to add a backslash before each paren in a string you could use the following:

```
s = s.replace('(', '\\(').replace(')', '\\)')
```

Or with regular expressions:

```
import re
s = re.sub(r'([()])', r'\\\1', s)
```

Note that you can also use a raw string literal by adding a the letter `r` before the opening quote, this makes it so that backslash is interpreted literally and no escaping is done.  So `r'foo\bar'` would be the same as `'foo\\bar'`.  So you could rewrite the first approach like the following:

```
s = s.replace('(', r'\(').replace(')', r'\)')
```

Note that even in raw string literals you can use a backslash to escape the quotation mark used for the string literal, so `r'we\'re'` is the same as `'we\'re'` or `"we're"`.  This is why raw string literals don't work well when you want the final character to be a backslash, for example `r'testme\'` (this will be a syntax error because the string literal is never closed).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re  
>>> strs = "(hi)"
>>> re.sub(r'([()])',r'\\\g<0>',strs)
'\\(hi\\)'
```

`"\"` is invalid because you're escaping the closing quote here, so python will raise EOF error.

So you must escape the `\` first using another `\`:

```
>>> "\\"
'\\'
>>> "\"
  File "<ipython-input-23-bdc6fd40f381>", line 1
    "\"
      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

>>>
```