# python: escape all escaped characters

Tags: python

I need to doubly escape all escaped characters in a string in python.  So, for example, any instances of `'\n'` need to be replaced by `'\\n'`  I can easily do this one character at a time with

```
s = s.replace('\n', '\\n')
s = s.replace('\r', '\\r')
# etc...
```

But I'm wondering if there's a one-off way to handle all of them.

Comment: Related question, [Escape special characters in a Python string - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/escape-special-characters-in-a-python-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr` returns the string representation of a string... which sounds redundant except that it double-escapes escape characters like you would if you typed them in yourself. It also encloses the string in quotes, but that can be easily removed.

```
>>> repr('\n\t\r')[1:-1]
'\\n\\t\\r'
```

Comment: With Python2, it will also escape/encode non-ascii characters (not sure if that is what the OP expected).

Comment: @ekhumoro Yes, you are quite right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @ekhumoro In my case non-ascii characters aren't a concern, but it's good to know for the future.

Comment: This will escape actual backslashes too many times.

Comment: @wim - I don't think so. If we had the single character `"\\"`, it would turn it into the two character `"\\\\"`. If you viewed it as a list `print(list(repr("\\"))[1:-1])` you'd get `['\\', '\\']`.

Comment: @tdelaney Hmm, can't exactly remember what I was thinking in that comment from 2 years ago, but expected behavior would be to _not_ escape the actual backslash (since it is not an escaped character in the original string). e.g. The result for input r'a\b' should just be `'a\\b'` again and not `'a\\\\b'` like this code gives.

Comment: @wim - oops - should have checked more carefully. I got a comment notification plus a downvote for this answer... I assumed they were both for the same answer. Now I have to reply to the _real_ comment I skipped.