# How to dynamically add escape character for any character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I have got **p** element with some text. In this text in HTML code I use some "escape" characters like *\n*, *\?*, *\t*, etc. When I get the string in JS code, it is treated as *\\n*, *\\?*, *\\t*. I want to replace it for **REAL** escaped characters as below in the snippet.

I want to change all **"\\char"** from the string into output escaped **"\char"**.

It works when I replace all the characters separately (as below), but I wonder how to do that **once** for all characters preceded by \ in my text.

I need something like this:

```
.replace(/\\/,'\')
```

or something like this:

```
.replace(/\\(.)/,'\$1')
```

but it does not work because the slash **\** makes the following sign **'** or **$** escaped in the code. Is there any way to insert escape character other than use **\** ?

```js
var input = document.getElementById('sampInput');
var output = document.getElementById('sampOutput');

var parsedInput = input.innerHTML
                   .replace(/\\n/g,'\n')
                   .replace(/\\t/g,'\t')
                   .replace(/\\\*/g,'*')
                   .replace(/\\\?/g,'?');

output.innerHTML = parsedInput;
```

```css
p {
  white-space:pre;
}
```

```html
<h4>Input:</h4>
<p id="sampInput">hello\nworld\nhello\tworld\nsome \? character and another \* character</p>

<h4>Output:</h4>
<p id="sampOutput"></p>
```

Comment: What do you expect `\*` or `\?` to mean? Like, what Unicode code point do you want that to be? They're not standard JavaScript escape codes like `\t` and `\n`.

Comment: Yes I know. I just want to get the same effect as you get with any escaped character in your JS string `console.log("some\*text\?sample"); \\some*text?sample`

Comment: Pawle, `"some\*text\?sample"` =  `"some*text?sample"`, that string literal of yours contains no literal backslashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct way to do what you're asking, but you can write some code to do it:

```
var charmap = {
  n: "\n",
  r: "\r",
  f: "\f",
  t: "\t",
  b: "\b"
};
var replaced = string.replace(/\\(.)/g, function(_, char) {
  return (char in charmap) ? charmap[char] : char;
});
```

If you wanted to additionally parse `\uNNNN` escapes, that'd be a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody landed here looking for the same in Python, use `re.escape(str)`
Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/escape-special-characters-in-a-python-string) for more detailed discussion