# What are all the ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS from openpyxl?

Tags: python, regex, compilation, python-re, illegal-characters

We are running into a problem when parsing emails with python from outlook. Sometimes emails have characters that are not able to be appended to an excel worksheet using openpyxl. The error it raises is just `IllegalCharacterError`.

I am trying to force this to print out the actual characters that are considered "Illegal".

That said while doing some digging in one of the files in opnepyxl I found on `cell.py` this line that raises the error.

```
if next(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.finditer(value), None):
    raise IllegalCharacterError
```

So navigating to where `ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE` is defined we find:

```
ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE = re.compile(r'[\000-\010]|[\013-\014]|[\016-\037]')
```

So I tried to `print(ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE)` in the hopes it might print out the values it is representing. As I am not very skilled in regex or the use of compile I was not sure what would happen but sadly all I got printed out to console was `re.compile(r'[\000-\010]|[\013-\014]|[\016-\037]')`.

Can someone help me figure out how to print these values or at the very least understand how to find what these values represent?

Answer (score 1):

In Regular Expression, or Regex for short, the output you are seeing is an expression of certain characters in a given range. For example:

**First part of RE:**

```
[\000-\010]
```

This means that this set contains any character from 0 to 8 (char codes 0 to 8), which are control characters. You could be getting any character from **NULL** (�) to **BS** (backspace).

**Second part of RE:**

```
[\013-\014]
```

Again, this is more control characters. Specifically, characters from 11 to 12 (char code 11 to 12). Which can be from **VT** or **FF**. Note that **VT** is actually tabulation which cannot be printable.

**Third part of RE:**

```
[\016-\037]
```

Now this is a bit more interesting, as this contains both **control characters** as well as **printable characters**. So with this being said, you could expect to get any character from 14 to 31 (char code 14 to 31).

So the only logical reason why it cannot print any illegal characters is because the RE that has been provided simply does not entail printable characters. Any ASCII character after 33 is a **printable character** *(32 is the space character)*, but as you can see here, your code takes everything from \000 to \037. So you're trying to print control characters that aren't printable.

Here is a ASCII table for reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

I hope this helps!

Comment: Well actually you can print them. They just print as squares. I already figured out how to print them by writing the byte string and decoding it. I think the solution is to convert the string I get from the email body and then convert that to byte and then replace any byte code that is "illegal" according to openpyxl with a space or something. I do find it very odd that openpyxl considers 33 through 37 to be illegal though. Those are printable and I move them all the time so I found that a bit odd its in the regex.

Comment: Cannot test until I get back to work Monday though. Thanks for the details and the reference link.

Comment: No problem! I hope I did shine some light on your problem.

Comment: Here is what I used to at least decode the bytecode and print what could be printed. `x = b'\000\010\013\014\016\017\018\019\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\028\029\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037'
print(x.decode())`