# How to handle the " sign in python strings

Tags: python, html, string

I have to include the following text in a python string:

```
<table style="width:100%">
```

But since python uses the " sign to start and close strings, when i try to put the code above into a python string the part - `<table style=` is recognized as a string but the second part isn't because python recognize the " sign as the end of the string.

How can I solve this problem ? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can either escape it, or use `'` to enclose the string.  So: `s = '<table style="width:100%">'` or `s = "<table style=\"width:100%\">"`

Comment: Man that was so obvious, why didn't I think about it.. thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python escape regex special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/python-escape-regex-special-characters)

Comment: BTW, `"` is a _character_, not _"sign"_