# Incorporating special characters in Python's re.compile

Tags: python, regex

**Concise description**

I am working on a project where I have a list of keywords(has special character in it) and I have a string, I have to check whether any of the keywords are present in that string and extract the same. It is going to be a case insensitive search. But the exact keyword has to be present. If `SAP` is a keyword then `sap` is a positive hit while `saphire` is a negative hit.

I have put in a lot of efforts, but I could only achieve output which is partially what I am looking for.

This is a sample code for you to understand :

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP(2.0)"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % w for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = "HIPAAA and ERP(2.0)"
>>> r.findall(word)
['']
```

here I should be getting this output - `["ERP(2.0)"]`

I have checked out this question : [Escape regex special characters in a Python string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202538/escape-regex-special-characters-in-a-python-string) but this doesnt really answer my question.

can anyone please guide me how to make this work, considering I have 10's of keywords which has special character in it, and I am importing those keywords from MySQL?

**Detailed description**

Test 1

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % w for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = "HIPAA and ERP"
>>> r.findall(word)
['HIPAA', 'ERP']
```

Test 2

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP(2.0)"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % w for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = "HIPAA and ERP(2.0)"
>>> r.findall(word)
['']
```

Test 3

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP\(2.0\)"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % w for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = "HIPAA and ERP(2.0)"
>>> r.findall(word)
['HIPAA']
```

Test 4

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP(2.0)"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(w) for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = r"HIPAASTOL and ERP(2.0)"
>>> r.findall(word)
[]
```

Test 5

```
>>> keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP(2.0)"]
>>> r = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
>>> word = r"HIPAASTOL and ERP(2.0)"
>>> r.findall(word)
['HIPAA', 'ERP(2.0)']
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Special characters have to be escaped.
2. By definition, a word boundary `\b` is a zero-length assertion that matches a ... boundary between a word character `\w` or `[a-zA-z0-9_]` and a non word character `\W` or `[a-zA-z0-9_]`.

In your case, you have the regex: `\bHIPAA\b|\bERP(2.0)\b`

There're no problem with the former `\bHIPAA\b` but the later `\bERP(2.0)\b` shows 2 errors.

1. the parens have to be escaped.
2. the last word boundary requires a word character just after the closing parens.

To escape special characters, you have to use `re.escape` function:

```
re.escape(w) for w in keywords
```

To detect word boundaries without using `\b`, you have to assert there're no word character before and after the keywords, for that you have to use lookaround:

- `(?<!\w)` before the keyword, negative lookbehind, make sure we haven't a word character before
- `(?!\w)` after the keyword, negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a word character after.

You regex becomes:

```
r = re.compile('|'.join([r'(?<!\w)%s(?!\w)' % re.escape(w) for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/LjCL9i/1)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
keywords = ["HIPAA", "ERP(2.0)"]
r = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in keywords]), flags=re.I)
word = r"HIPAA and ERP(2.0)"
r.findall(word)
```

**output**

```
['HIPAA', 'ERP(2.0)']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have updated the question a bit, can you please have a look?

Comment: If I am adding this condition `'\b%s\b'` , the output is not coming. updated the question as well, can you please check once?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, can you please check this once?