# sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Tags: python

I'm testing on my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os,sys
import glob
import commands
import gzip
from itertools import islice

f1=gzip.open("/home/xug/scratch/test_trim.fastq","w")
LIST=[]
N = 4
with open("/home/xug/scratch/test.fastq", "r") as f:
    while True:
        line_group = list(islice(f, N))
        if not line_group:
            break
        l3=line_group[3].rstrip()
        l3_trim=commands.getoutput("sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'" + l3)
        #l3_to = subprocess.Popen(["sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g'",l3],
                                  #stdout=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=1)
        #l3_trim=l3_to.stdout
        if ( float(len(l3_trim))/float(len(l3)) > 0.70 ):
               LIST.append(line_group[0])
               LIST.append(line_group[1][:int(len(l3_trim))])
               LIST.append(line_group[2])
               LIST.append(l3_trim)

    output=f1.writelines(LIST)
```

However I got errors like:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Eventually to put an end to the while loop....

Comment: Start with the most basic question: What does `l3` contain?

Comment: l3, is a variable: l3=list[3]

Comment: I see that in your code (actually, `l3=line_group[3]`). But that still tells us nothing about what the *contents* of that variable are. If you don't know, try the `print` statement.

Comment: Very good question. Please see my new edit.(There's sth. wrong with print l3 content, actually)

Comment: There's something wrong with number of elements you get back from islice(). There's no element 3.

Comment: Why there's no element 3?  There are 4 elements in each list(islice)....

Comment: What happens when your loop encounters the end of the file? There's no way out of your `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah, I understand....But another problem is: commands.getoutput("sed 's/\(.\)B*$/\1/g' " + l3)  There must be something wrong this this command

Comment: It appears that `l3` contains characters such as the backtick, which means something special to the shell. The shell is giving errors because you haven't quoted those characters properly. But why are you using `sed` to process your data anyway? That's going to be *really* slow. Instead, do whatever you need to do using Python's built-in string handling functions.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot. I use sed, because I used to write bash code for this problem; and now change from bash to python. For l3, there used to be a '\n' at the end; but I've deleted that using rstrip()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>(continuing from the comments above)</sub>

To remove trailing `B` from a string using Python's built-in `re` module, try:

```
import re

l3_trim = re.sub(r"B*$", "", l3)
```

Comment: oh, thanks so much....but I'm still curious about how to use commands.getoutput+sed

Comment: You have to quote the shell metacharacters. See [How to escape os.system() calls in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls-in-python) for more information.