# Python only passing the first word of my string to subprocess

Tags: function, python-2.7, espeak

So i'm a week into learning python, apologies if this is obvious, can anyone tell me why i only get the first word of my sentence passed to espeak when i call the following functions yet the print command below it prints the whole thing? if i replace +x in the subprocess call with the text i want it works fine, is there some change of formatting i'm missing like somehow making my variable a string?

```
def speech(text):
    import subprocess
    x = text
    subprocess.call('espeak '+x, shell=True)
    print x

def exit():
    speech("Goodbye Slacker")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `shell=True` (since it can be a [security risk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module), and [properly quoting the text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817/190597) can be a nuisance). Instead, use `shell=False` and pass the arguments in a list:

```
subprocess.call(['espeak', x], shell=False)
```