# making a GIF from imges in any order with python

Tags: python, animation, python-imaging-library, gif

I'm trying to make a gif out of a sequence of png format pics with python language in ubuntu 12.04. I have a file which my pictures are in it. they are named as, lip_shapes1.png to lip_shapes11.png. also I have a list with names of images in it which i want to make that gif in this sequence. the list looks like this:

```
list = [lip_shapes1.png, lip_shapes4.png , lip_shapes11.png, lip_shapes3.png]
```

but my problem is that i found this code :

```
import os
os.system('convert   -loop 0   lip_shapes*.gnp   anime.gif')
```

but it only makes gif in the order of the gnp's names, but I want it to be in any order I want. is it possible?

if anybody can help me i really appreciate it.

thanks in advance

PS: i also want to make a movie out of it. i tried this code(shapes is my list of images names):

```
    s = Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'image2', '-r', '24', '-i'] + shapes + ['-vcodec', 'mpeg4', '-y', 'movie.mp4'])
s.communicate()
```

but it gives me this in terminal and doesnt work:

> The ffmpeg program is only provided for script compatibility and will be removed
>   in a future release. It has been deprecated in the Libav project to allow for
>   incompatible command line syntax improvements in its replacement called avconv
>   (see Changelog for details). Please use avconv instead.
>
> Input #0, image2, from 'shz8.jpeg':
>     Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 266x212 [PAR 1:1 DAR 133:106], 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc

shz8.jpeg is the first name on the list.

thanks

Comment: `convert -loop 0 lip_shapes1.png lip_shapes2.png  lip_shapes3.png lip_shapes4.png ... anime.gif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a list of images you want to convert into gif as a python list. You can sort it or arrange in any order you want. e.g

`img_list = ['lip_shapes1.png', 'lip_shapes4.png' , 'lip_shapes11.png', 'lip_shapes3.png']
img_list.sort()`

Please note that `list` should not be used as variable name, because it's a name of list type.

Then you can use this list in calling `os.system(convert ...)` e.g.

`os.system('convert -loop 0 %s anime.gif' % ' '.join(img_list))`

Comment: i used your way, that is exactly what i wanted.

Comment: @ShahrzadA: In that case (if you think it's useful) it would be nice if you accept my post (mark tick below it) or upwote it.

Comment: do you also know how to make a mp4 from  sequence of images like i mentioned before?

Comment: @ShahrzadA: you should ask separate question for that. However I believe that question would be out of scope of stackoverflow, so better place to ask would be [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 2):

If you use `subprocess.call`, you can pass the filenames as a list of strings. This will avoid [shell quotation issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35817/190597) that might arise if the filenames, for example, contained quotes or spaces.

```
import subprocess
shapes = ['lip_shapes1.png', 'lip_shapes4.png' , 'lip_shapes11.png', 'lip_shapes3.png']
cmd = ['convert', '-loop0'] + shapes + ['anime.gif']
retcode = subprocess.call(cmd)
if not retval == 0:
    raise ValueError('Error {} executing command: {}'.format(retcode, cmd))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure to handle a few things here, if you want to read a series of pngs from a folder, I recommend using a for loop to check for the ending of the file, i.e. .png, .jpg, etc. I wrote a blog post on how to easily do this (read about it [here](https://engineersportal.com/blog/2018/7/27/how-to-make-a-gif-using-python-an-application-with-the-united-states-wind-turbine-database)):

```
image_file_names = [],[]
for file_name in os.listdir(png_dir):
    if file_name.endswith('.png'):
        image_file_names.append(file_name)
        sorted_files = sorted(image_file_names, key=lambda y: int(y.split('_')[1]))
```

This will put all the '.png' files into one vector of file names. From there, you can loop through the files to customize the gif using the following:

```
images = []
frame_length = 0.5 # seconds between frames
end_pause = 4 # seconds to stay on last frame
# loop through files, join them to image array, and write to GIF called 'test.gif'
for ii in range(0,len(sorted_files)):       
    file_path = os.path.join(png_dir, sorted_files[ii])
    if ii==len(sorted_files)-1:
        for jj in range(0,int(end_pause/frame_length)):
            images.append(imageio.imread(file_path))
    else:
        images.append(imageio.imread(file_path))
# the duration is the time spent on each image (1/duration is frame rate)
imageio.mimsave('test.gif', images,'GIF',duration=frame_length)
```

here's an example produced by the method above:

[image: GIF Example]

https://engineersportal.com/blog/2018/7/27/how-to-make-a-gif-using-python-an-application-with-the-united-states-wind-turbine-database