# Reconstructing command line arguments string

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string containing arguments e.g `python program_name.py arg1 arg2`. I want to add an argument in a certain index, e.g 2, so, as in array indexing, it should result like this: `python program_name.py my_argument arg1 arg2`.

In this case, there is no problem, I can just use:

```
s = "python program_name.py arg1 arg2"
l = s.split()
l.insert(2, "my_argument")
print "My final result:", ' '.join(l)
```

BUT, what happens if one of the arguments includes spaces? say a string argument like this `Wow, this is a long argument`. When using it in the command like it obviously is wrapped with `"`, how can I, then, accomplish my mission?

Example string: `python program_name.py "My long string argument" another_one and_another_one`

how do I end up with `python program_name.py my_argument "My long string argument" another_one and_another_one` ?

Comment: How did you get the arguments string? sys.argv is already split up for you, just insert to that list, wrap all elements in double-quotes and join.

Comment: I would just put quotes around all arguments, and not worry about it, but this is more correct:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls-in-python (use shlex.quote or pipes.quote, depending on python version)

Comment: The duplicate looks the same as your post, If it does not answer your post, please [edit] the question.

Comment: @BhargavRao It does answer! Thank you and sorry for the duplicate, I did not find that question when I searched