# Python3 replace automaticaly single quote by \'

Tags: python, quote

I am doing a python3 software that use google_speech and and os.system command.

Everything work fine but when a user enter a string with the ' character I have this error :  Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

This is my code :

```
def textToSpeak():
global fieldValues

msg = "Enter the text to speak\n\nDon't use" +str(" \' ")+str(" write it like this : je tinvite chez moi, not je t\'invite chez moi ")
title = "Enter the text to speak"
fieldNames = ["Text to speak"]
fieldValues = []
fieldValues = multenterbox(msg, title, fieldNames)
speak()

def speak():
global lang, fieldValues
textValue = "google_speech -l" +str(lang) +str(" \'\"")+str(fieldValues[0])+str("\"\'")
os.system(textValue)
```

Comment: please correct the indentation

Comment: also please post the full error with stacktrace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape os.system() calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls)

Comment: Thou shalt use the `subprocess` module and provide commands as a list to it!

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on `os.system`, you want [`shlex.quote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html?highlight=quote#shlex.quote):

> Return a shell-escaped version of the string s. The returned value is a string that can safely be used as one token in a shell command line, for cases where you cannot use a list.

That said, I'd strongly recommend moving to [the `subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) (`subprocess.call` would be the simplest replacement for `os.system` here, though there are other options), and passing your arguments in list form, allowing `subprocess` to do the work of escaping (when necessary on Windows), removing the need to manually add quotes, and avoiding string processing entirely on other OSes (where it can `exec` an argument vector directly, with no escapes needed).

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you're trying to escape your string input by the user.

You can use `repr()` for this, or `json.dumps()`.

```
>>> repr("je t'invite")
'"je t\'invite"'

>>> json.dumps("je t'invite")
'"je t\'invite"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer who works fine :

```
textValue = "google_speech -l" +str(lang) +str(" \"")+str(fieldValues[0].replace("'","\'"))+str("\"")
os.system(textValue)
```