# pytesseract tessedit_char_whitelist not accepting quote

Tags: python, tesseract, quotes, python-tesseract, pytesser

I have started working with pytesserract in python. When i pass it single or double quote in

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

tesseract_config = r"""-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#'<>(){};:"""
tesseract_language = "eng"

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('res/outc001.jpg'), lang=tesseract_language, config=tesseract_config)
print text
```

it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('res/outc001.jpg'), lang=tesseract_language, config=tesseract_config).split('\n')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 193, in image_to_string
    return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 106, in run_tesseract
    command += shlex.split(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 279, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 269, in next
    token = self.get_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 96, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py", line 172, in read_token
    raise ValueError, "No closing quotation"
ValueError: No closing quotation
```

I have been searching for a way to escape single and double quotes and none of them worked.

When i run tesseract as itself with

```
tesseract res/outc001.jpg tesseract_out/out001 -c "tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#\'\"<>(){};:"
```

it works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean "when I pass it single or double quote in"? It's not like you're manually calling tesseract with command line arguments; from the looks of the error message you're using `pytesseract.image_to_string`. What are `tesseract_language` and `tesseract_config`? GIve us a [mcve] to work with.

Comment: text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('res/outc001.jpg'), lang="eng", config= r"""-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ#'<>(){};:""")

But the language and config are in a separate file, and I have used every type of escaping quotesi found

Comment: You should [edit] that into the question.

Comment: There's a difference between the text you used in python and the text you used on the command line. You have to escape the quotes. I don't know why you did it on the command line but didn't do it in python.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls

Comment: I didn't know I have to escape them inside three double quotes, i thought i just put " inside three double quotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pytesseract uses [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) to separate config arguments.

The escape character for shlex is `\`, if you want to insert quotes in the `shlex.split()` function you must escape it with `\`.

- If you want `'` only in the whitelist:

  ```
  tesseract_config = "-c tessedit_char_whitelist=blahblah\\'")
  ```
- If you want `"` only:

  ```
  tesseract_config = '-c tessedit_char_whitelist=blahblah\\"')
  ```
- If you want both `'` and `"`:

  ```
  tesseract_config = '''-c tessedit_char_whitelist=blahblah\\'\\"''')
  ```

  or

  ```
  tesseract_config = """-c tessedit_char_whitelist=blahblah\\"\\'""")
  ```