# How do I escape/use single quotes in os.system command with python 2?

Tags: python, escaping, quotes

i have built a small script that runs a simple shell utility called imapsync, with a bunch of variables taken from a dictionary, the command is as follows:

```
os.system("imapsync --host1 %s --user1 %s --password1 '%s' --host2 %s --user2 %s --password2 '%s' --ssl1 --no-modulesversion --ssl2" % (fromHost, emails, passwords, toHost, emails, passwords))
```

the deal is that passwords often contain special characters, example: djDJS*^%%%^&)

this imapsync tool allows such characters if enclosed in single quotes: 'djDJS*^%%%^&)'

what I am trying to achieve is post the single quotes in the command, itself.. I tried "'", backquotes - ``, escaped quotes - \'\', enclosing the command in single quotes, nothing worked thus far

Comment: How do you determine, that the single quotes are not escaped if you use for example double backslashes?

Comment: the command outputs something such as:
"expecting matching ( character, exiting..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape os.system() calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls)

Comment: Do you really have to use `os.system()`? Could use `subprocess.call()` instead, so that you can pass an array of arguments rather than a string that needs parsing?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the documentation of imapsync, I found the recommendation to enclose [passwords in double quotes within single quotes to avoid common problems](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync/blob/e2daa4f91f541fd0fd936f23f934825ae83f0d6d/FAQ.d/FAQ.Passwords_on_Unix.txt#L14).

Since you already start the string with double quotes, you have to escape the double quotes around your password with a backslash `\"`.

There are also two things you could do to make your code even better.
First, you can use [`.format` syntax for string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of the old `%` syntax.

Second replace `os.system` with  [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). This allows you to split your command string into a list of all arguments, which looks more clear.

Your new code would look like

```
import subprocess

args = [
  "imapsync",
  "--host1",
  fromHost,
  "--user1",
  emails,
  "--password1",
  "'\"{}\"'".format(passwords),
  "--host2",
  toHost,
  "--user2",
  emails,
  "--password2",
  "'\"{}\"'".format(passwords),
  "--ssl1",
  "--no-modulesversion",
  "--ssl2"
]

p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output = p.communicate()[0]

print(output)
```

In this example [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) is used to gather the output of the imapsync command as a string.
The `communicate` method returns a  tuple with the outputs of the subprocess to `stdout` and `stderr` streams.

If you also want to read  the output to `stderr` from the subprocess, change the code as following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

output, errors = p.communicate()

print(output)
print(errors)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, would it be possible to explain the last 3 lines :)

Answer (score -1):

The best format for passing string parameters in Python is to use the format string method. You could do something like this:

```
line_command = "imapsync --host1 {fromHost} --user1 {emails} --password1 '\"{passwords}\"' --host2 {toHost} --user2 {emails} --password2 '\"{passwords}\"' --ssl1 --no-modulesversion --ssl2".format(fromHost=fromHost, emails=emails, passwords=passwords, toHost=toHost)
os.system(line_command)
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question about escaping. `%` and `.format` are equivalent, the way you're using it.