# subprocess syntax to execute quoted awk command line script

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the best way to execute `awk` command below in Python 3?

```sh
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' file1.csv > file2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module to perform arbitrary commands from Python:

```py
import os

os.system('do some command')
```

Comment: Thanks David for your quick response. When I try that command with the single quotes, I get SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal.  My command was       os.system('awk -F'"' -v OFS= '' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", " ", $i) } 1' dhcp_option6.csv > dhcp_option6_modified.csv')

Comment: it's seeing the quotation marks and thinking the string is complete, read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the subprocess module - check_output
Example:

```
subprocess.check_output("awk...", shell=True)
```