# How do you escape text in Python for using in a Bash command?

Tags: python

How do you escape text so you can use it as a quoted argument in a Bash command?

I'm trying to run a command like:

```
os.system(f'mycommand.py "{some_value_generated_by_python}"')
```

[Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817/how-to-escape-os-system-calls) to similar questions have suggested `shlex.quote()` or `pipes.quote()`, but none of these work inside quoted arguments because these both escape single and double quotes by wrapping them inside single or double quotes, which isn't proper shell escaping.

I also can't use unquoted arguments because my string may contain spaces, and naturally, neither method escapes spaces at all.

So if my value was "Hello y'all", it would generate a command like:

```
sh mycommand.py "Hello y"'"all"
```

which isn't a valid command syntax.

I could write some regexes to do the escaping, but is there some pre-existing function to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `subprocess.run` or `subprocess.call`, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html, which take their arguments in a list, as in

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["mycommand.py", "Hello y'all"])
# make sure mycommand.py is in your path, or use /path/to/mycommand.py
```

This way allows for quotes, spaces, tabs, and much more fun that will not be interfered with by an intermediate shell.